# Notification preference

Tags: support

How does one change one's notification preference?  I was asked after I posted my first question, but I can't find anything in my profile about my choice.

Comment: What does "notification preference" mean?

Comment: By "Notification Preference" I mean how soon one should be notified of new answers or comments on questions or comments on answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/

Specifically the "email settings" area on the Stack Exchange drop down menu at the top left of the browser:

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/global-inbox-email-link.png))</sub>